# Trying to create Rollup but values not showing up in Field to Aggregate

Tags: visualforce, soql, javascript

here is my ServiceItem_Summary view:
[image]

However when I try to create a rollup summary in Case, my newly added field NonWarrantedServiceType is not showing up in the Field to Aggregate drop down.  Do you know why?
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Formula fields are not available for Roll up summaries.  If you need to roll up this field, what I would recommend is a workflow that copies the formula value to a text or numeric field. Then, roll that field up.